# Pentaho- How do I view the backend sql of reports?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

I have currently managed to get access to the Pentaho User console and have 4 reports that I plan to migrate to an alternate BI platform ( say Power BI or SSRS)

Within Pentaho user console, I can view the reports, my home page also shows me option to create new report/ Manage data sources.

However, I am unable to view the dataset/ query behind any of these 4 reports. I would like to know which are the tables being referred to in these reports and the basically want to reuse the SQL query.

NOTE- My user console does not show an option to EDIT an existing report.

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't edit Pentaho Reports(.prpt) in pentaho CDE(BI Server), you have to open the files in pentaho report designer itself.
2. For dashboards we do have option, every dashboard file will create two other files along with CDE, you can edit the CDA file by going into browse files and execute the query and see the result.

Comment: Hand- Thank you so much!! Appreciate your help. I am accessing the Hitachi "Pentaho User Console" ( URL-->login with my lanid) and assume this is same as the dashboard you are referring to?

Comment: I can see the "Browse files" option but cant seem to find any CDA/CDE file. I tried downloading one of the Reports and can see XANALYZER file along with LOCALE file. Sorry if these are too basic , but cant seem to find my way around these somehow :(

Comment: CDA/CDE will file only appear if you are creating CDE dashboard, for report it will not come, answer to your original question you can not preview your query result or query directly in pentaho server.

Comment: Thank you. I'm told that the reports were built using pentagon report analyzer and workbench. I'm trying to get the Sql that's being used, but just don't know how to.  :(

Comment: if reports are being developed using analyzer. on home screen you will see manage data-source option, from there select the data-source name given and click on edit tab, you will see columns of the query.